# How to access AWS Cognito from Private Subnet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-vpc, vpc-endpoint

I know that currently there is no VPC Endpoint for AWS Cognito. Is there any alternative way to communicate with cognito from private subnet ?

Comment: You should be able to communicate with cognito without VPC endpoint as well. Why is that you require the call to cognito to go through VPC endpoint?

Comment: without NAT GATEWAY.

Comment: Is there any way to do this from private subnet without using a NAT gateway?